# Jquery add multy image to one input file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

i have a edit action in asp mvc controller. this action return a json response that this response contain multi image that every image have a name and data byte array.
in view i have a input element that shows in bottom:

```
<input id="InptGalleryImg" type="file" style="display:none;" name="InptGalleryImg" multiple />
```

now in view jquery i get this json request and i want add those images to this input element.

note: i use this input to update database photos.

anybody have solution for me?

thanks.

Comment: So you simply want to display the images that are in a data byte array? Does that have anything to do with your `<input>`? I'm a little confused with your question.

Comment: no i want add this image to input file upload that change image(remove or add new ) and post this input to [httppost] action in controller. (i use this trick to create action but i confused for edit)